# Does anyone know how to turn off MUnit Coverage analysis?

Tags: maven, munit

After my mock testing is complete and successful, the Maven plugin starts this:

[org.mule.munit.remote.CoverageManager]Calculating application coverage for resources:app-config.xml

I removed the configuration in my POM where coverage was set to "true". I changed to "false" and the coverage analysis continues.

Does anyone know how to turn this off?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0   http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.dlw</groupId>
    <artifactId>billing-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>mule</packaging>
    <name>Acme Billing API Application</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

    <mule.version>3.8.0</mule.version>
    <mule.tools.version>1.1</mule.tools.version>
    <munit.version>1.2.0</munit.version>
    <mule.munit.support.version>3.8.0</mule.munit.support.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-app-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.tools.version}</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <copyToAppsDirectory>true</copyToAppsDirectory>
            <inclusions>
                    <inclusion>
                        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mule-module-apikit</artifactId>
                    </inclusion>
                </inclusions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>project</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-resource</id>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-resource</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/app/</directory>
                            </resource>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>mappings/</directory>
                            </resource>
                        <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/api/</directory>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.munit.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>munit-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${munit.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>test</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/munit</directory>
        </testResource>
    <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
        </testResource>
    <testResource>
            <directory>src/main/app</directory>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
</build>

<!-- Mule Dependencies -->
<dependencies>
    <!-- Xml configuration -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-core-ee</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Xml configuration -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-spring-config-ee</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Mule Transports -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-transport-file</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-transport-http</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.transports</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-transport-jdbc-ee</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.transports</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-transport-jms-ee</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-transport-vm</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Mule Modules -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-scripting</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-xml</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- for testing -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.tests</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-tests-functional</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-apikit</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.3</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-http</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hoeggsoftware</groupId>
        <artifactId>acme-mule-domain</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <type>zip</type>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.mulesoft.weave</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-plugin-weave_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.mulesoft.munit</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-munit-support</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.munit.support.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.mulesoft.munit</groupId>
        <artifactId>munit-runner</artifactId>
        <version>${munit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>Hoegg</id>
        <name>Hoegg Software</name>
        <url>http://maven.hoegg.software:8081/nexus/content/repositories/MuleRepository/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>Central</id>
        <name>Central</name>
        <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
        <name>MuleSoft Releases Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>Hoegg</id>
        <name>Hoegg Software</name>
        <url>http://maven.hoegg.software:8081/nexus/content/repositories/MuleRepository/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </pluginRepository>    
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>mulesoft-release</id>
        <name>mulesoft release repository</name>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: Can you post your POM and how you are launching Maven?

Comment: Added POM to initial post. And, when I run in terminal window : mvn clean package everything works without an issue. When I right-mouse/run/MUnit in Studio, the coverage analysis kicks off after successful tests. The errors are in the coverage analysis I think.

Comment: P.S. when running Maven in terminal, the log says "Not gathering coverage data". This comes with configuration set to false or no configuration at all for coverage analysis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to turn off coverage analysis when MUnit is run:

1. Do not provide any configuration in the MUnit plugin section within
2. Set run coverage to false like so:

   ```
   <configuration>
     <coverage>
       <runCoverage>false</runCoverage>
       <formats>
         <format>html</format>
       </formats>
     </coverage>
   </configuration>
   ```

NOTE: this configuration does not affect the behavior of MUnit within Anypoint Studio 6.0.3. The coverage analysis will still run if you select the MUnit test configuration (XML) and right-mouse/Run/MUnit

Comment: you're quite right. 
Currently there is no way to turn off coverage when running test from inside Anypoint Studio, and the configuration in the pom file is not the way. 

This feature (turn off coverage from inside Anypoint Studio) will be added in the next release